# Python os.write(filehandler, data) : TypeError An Integer Required

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I get Attribute Error: 'int' object has no attribute 'write'.

Here is a part of my script

```
data = urllib.urlopen(swfurl)

        save = raw_input("Type filename for saving. 'D' for same filename")

        if save.lower() == "d":
        # here gives me Attribute Error

            fh = os.open(swfname,os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREAT|os.O_TRUNC)
            fh.write(data)

        # #####################################################
```

Here is error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download.py", line 41, in <module>
    fh.write(data)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Answer (score 3):

`os.open` returns file descriptor. Use `os.write` to write into open file

```
import os
# Open a file
fd = os.open( "foo.txt", os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT | os.O_TRUNC)
# Write one string
os.write(fd, "This is test")
# Close opened file
os.close( fd )
```

Or better use python files if You don't need any low level API

```
with open('foo.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write('this is test')
```

Answer (score 1):

`os.open()` returns a file descriptor (an integer), not a file object. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open):

> **Note**: This function is intended for low-level I/O. For normal usage, use the built-in function `open()`, which returns a “file
>   object” with `read()` and `write()` methods (and many more). To wrap a
>   file descriptor in a “file object”, use `fdopen()`.

You should use the builtin `open()` function instead:

```
fh = open(swfname, 'w')
fh.write(data)
fh.close()
```

Or a context manager:

```
with open(swfname, 'w') as handle:
    handle.write(data)
```

Comment: In this situation, the builtin open() is not appropriate because it lacks the low-level API necessary to pass the flags O_WRONLY, O_CREAT, & O_TRUNC. The poster is correct to use os.open(). In case you're not familiar with this mechanism, see @oleg's answer, which outlines both the builtin open() and os.open(), and gives some guidance as to when to use os.open().